# Datasets of legal correspondences

Tags: nlp, legal

I am searching for datasets of legal correspondences between for example lawyers.
For example, a response to a complaint from an airline customer.

Preferably the legal basis should be with respect to the **European Union**. I got the hot tip of searching at public institution, but could not find any.

Answer (score 0):

Lawyers read things into the public record all the time,
which can then be retrieved by a
[FOIA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_of_Information_Act_(United_States))
or similar request,
or can simply be retrieved from public websites.

For example, while not directly sent by lawyers, all of the code enforcement letters posted
[here](https://www.hcd.ca.gov/planning-and-community-development/accountability-and-enforcement)
address particulars of law and sound exactly like letters from lawyers.
(Look for `enforcement-letters-issued.xlsx`.)
It comes with categorical metadata describing
the one-or-more specific laws relevant to a municipality's situation.

Train a [language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) [model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation) on the repeatedly used phrases,
and use that to focus your google searches.

Comment: thanks, do you know an equivalent for european law ?